# Run code before onCreateView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, android-lifecycle

I want to run some code in a `Fragment` before the `onCreateView` method is called. I want to show an `AlertDialog` and I want to call `onCreateView` the first time if the user clicks on the positive button. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. You can show a dialog and `commit` a `transaction` for that fragment on the user click.